# How to allow water to drain from my driveway?

Tags: water, drainage

My driveway is sloped in such a way that all the runoff goes to this one corner, but it readily gets blocked with debris from the trees. What can I do to keep the water flowing, other than regularly clearing the needles?
[image: establishing shot]

[image: close up]

Comment: Need more pics with better context.  Show us where the water is coming from, and where it's going.

Comment: That first pic pretty much shows it all. It’s coming from the surrounding paved surface and draining into the dirt at the corner in the center of the picture.

Comment: Shoot, man, then all you gotta do is dump some #1 or #2 stone in that corner and spread it out a little.

Answer (score 1):

- Install a dry well there

  - A dry well is a hole, filled with gravel, into which the water can run and collect without puddling on the surface, until it seeps out the bottom.
- Extend the curb down to the white wall

  - This will keep the water flowing along the concrete. It won't prevent the water flow from being slowed by needles, but it should continue to flow.
- Dig a channel along the concrete down to the white wall.

  - This would help the water flow along the dirt instead of puddling here.
- Do nothing.

  - The water will puddle then seep into the ground right here. So long as it doesn't completely flood & wash out the dirt/make the drive impassible, it's not a horrible solution.

Comment: Oh nice I like the dry well idea. Not so sure the other suggestions will work because that corner is the low spot — the white wall is slightly uphill.

Comment: If this spot is high, @RobinDavis, and there's a better location further downhill, you could put the dry well down hill somewhere that's a better location and just bury a perforated drain pipe to make the water flow easily there.

Comment: @RobinDavis - wow, my brain has a hard time seeing that the white wall is uphill...

Comment: This is the logical place for the water to drain, I think. The main issue is that it’s just this little concrete corner and it gets blocked up very easily.

Comment: I would literally wax the corner lightly to help prevent debris from sticking and piling up there so readily. Cheap white candles and a hair dryer would work. repeat every year.

Comment: A mere catchbasin (little drain inlet box - collector is also a term - generally quite a bit smaller than a full-on drywell) would likely work unless the ground is particularly non-porous. Mostly need a place for the needles to collect below ground level (will still need to clean it out occasionally.) A bit of grinding the concrete so the water passage is not so narrow would also help. But the wax is an easy approach to try.

Comment: Mine too, @JonCuster. I think it's just _slightly_ uphill and that disappears because the height of the camera is significantly more than the grade to the white wall. I'll trust our OP on this one... ;)

Comment: @Ecnerwal a catchbasin will need to be daylighted, so depending how far you need to go, it could be the same amount of work as a dry well (which I don't think is the right solution either).